# OpenMP unable to use multiple threads, no error associated with compilation

Tags: compiling, gcc, parallels

I am using openMP for my lab assignments and everything worked fine few weeks ago, but now it runs only on one thread, I've read and I guess that this is due to conflict between packages.  This is the code below:

```c
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallal
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello (%d)", id );
        printf("World (%d)\n", id);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get the output:

```
$ gcc -fopenmp hello.c
$ ./a.out
Hello (0)World (0)
```

I have tried reinstalling `gcc`, but to no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors in your code, that is why you are unable to use multiple threads.

**First Error** is a typo in `OMP Compiler Directives`. You have written

```
#pragma omp parallal
```

Correct one should be, (the word is parallel not parallal)

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

**Second Error** is an invalid `return 0` inside OpenMP structured block. The correct code should look like,

```c
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello (%d)", id );
        printf("World (%d)\n", id );
    }
return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
$ gcc prog.c -fopenmp
$ ./a.out
Hello (0)World (0)
Hello (2)World (2)
Hello (1)World (1)
Hello (3)World (3)
```

Comment: What a Mistake! Thanks for the help, you saved me.